# ERROR in NaN but they point to different modules. ... Webpack cannot distinguish on context and would fail to load the proper one

Tags: gradle, jhipster

ERROR in NaNbut they point to different modules "(/Users/USER/eclipse-workspace/nms/bin/main/webapp/app/admin/admin.module.ts and "/Users/USER/eclipse-workspace/nms/src/main/webapp/app/admin/admin.module.ts"). Webpack cannot distinguish on context and would fail to load the proper one.

I have done ./gradlew -Pprod
And with ./gradlew -Pprod --debug --info --scan --stacktrace
Gives this error: https://scans.gradle.com/s/czc6mol6ipsg6

Works well with ./gradlew 
and
./gradlew -Pdev bootWar

node version v10.13.0

jhipster version
Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
5.6.1

yarn --version
1.12.3

MacOS 10.12.6

Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error after upgrading JHipster from `5.7.2` to `5.8.2`
Finally I deleted `./bin/` folder and it resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was face same problem on my application and Finally I got a solution from Github issue in angular-cli Project. It's working fine for me. **Working code:**

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
     {
         loadChildren: "../<whatever the folder name of parent module>/admin/admin.module#AdminModule",
         path: "admin",
     },
];
```