# Jhipster jenkins: ERROR in NaNbut they point to different modules Webpack cannot distinguish on context and would fail to load

Tags: angular, jenkins, jhipster

I am trying to build a Jhipster project in Jenkins. The project runs fine in my local. However, it is throwing the below error in Jenkins run during 'yarn nun webpack:build'. Below is the error:

```
ERROR in NaNbut they point to different modules "(<jenkins wrokspace>/mybuild/target/myapp-snapshot-0.0.1.jar/app/admin//admin.module.ts and "<jenkins wrokspace>/mybuild/src/main/webapp/app/admin/admin.module.ts"). Webpack cannot distinguish on context and would fail to load the proper one.
```

adding the app-routing-mdule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { errorRoute } from './layouts/error/error.route';
import { navbarRoute } from './layouts/navbar/navbar.route';

const LAYOUT_ROUTES = [navbarRoute, ...errorRoute];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {
          path: 'admin',
          loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminUIModule,
        },
        
        ...LAYOUT_ROUTES,
      ],
      { enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED }
    ),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class RmrsAppRoutingModule {}
```

Please help me out. Let me know what else details need to be posted here.

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266712/error-in-nan-but-they-point-to-different-modules-webpack-cannot-distinguish When you say it runs fine locally, do you mean as a dev build or as a prod build? Do you run it with maven or gradle? Does your jenkins pipeline runs a clean before?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou: we are using maven. In jenkins, we are using prod build. In local we build it with npm and in Jenkins we build it using yarn. Jenkins pipeline do run a clean before.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have already taken a look into the stack overfolow question that u tagged. It was looking into bin folder, however mine is looking into target folder. not sure why

Comment: Comparing a local execution using npm with a jenkins execution using yarn seems a good recipe for getting into trouble. I would run the same for both to be sure it works. bin folder is for gradle  and target is for maven.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou: After running into the issue, used yarn execution in local as well.The local execution completed gracefully. Not sure what is the issue with app.route, why it is causing problem.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou added the app routing module.ts in case it helps in understanding

Comment: The loadChildren issue was also mentioned in the answers to the question I linked, the code you pasted cannot compile due to a missing quote on loadChildren line.. Why did you change what was generated by JHipster? https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/main/src/main/webapp/app/app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225521/discussion-between-bidisha-mukherjee-and-gael-marziou).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the target folder from the project and run the command again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).